Visiting visa to visit girlfriend in Japan from India
I am an Indian citizen with fresh passport who has recently started earning and recently, I have been planning to make a visit to my girlfriend(Indian) who works in Tokyo.
So far, I am not able to find any success stories for the visiting (friends) visa category around my friend circle for Japan. Moreover, when I search over net the results that come up are mostly on rejection.
My question is that is it an appropriate visa category for me to apply in first place? Or is it a mistake?
Any reasons why this category has a very low success rate?
If someone has had success with this, will be extremely thankful if you could share what all additional documents did you use to support your application.
Will be very helpful if you can take out few minutes and share your knowledge.
Thanks in advance!

This recent Travel.SE Question and Answer is almost identical.

The reason net search results are mostly on rejection is because successful applicants don’t need to post…
